# Rotated text with OpenVG

Tags: openvg

I've noticed that the OpenVG transformation matrix is ignored by the text rendering routine at all and I cannot control the text position with it manually with VG_GLYPH_ORIGIN `parameter`.

I'm implementing a scene graph. I found out that I can use `vgGetMatrix`, read components 6 and 7 of the current 3x3 transform matrix and set `VG_GLYPH_ORIGIN` to those values before drawing a block of text. This allows the text origin to be placed  in correct place, but the text is still always displayed left-to-right.

However, this itself doesn't enable me to do any other transformations, like rotation. I'm surprised because the text is composed from `VGPath`s and they are indeed transformed

Is there a way to make the text rotated with OpenVG 1.1? Or should I ignore the text functionality from OpenVG 1.1 and draw the letters as individual paths or images manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the draw functions use a different user->surface matrix:

- `vgDrawPath` uses `VG_MATRIX_PATH_USER_TO_SURFACE`
- `vgDrawImage` uses `VG_MATRIX_IMAGE_USER_TO_SURFACE`
- `vgDrawGlyph`/`vgDrawGlyphs` use `VG_MATRIX_GLYPH_USER_TO_SURFACE`

By default, all of the matrix functions (`vgTranslate`, `vgRotate`, `vgLoadMatrix`, etc) operate on `VG_MATRIX_PATH_USER_TO_SURFACE`. To change the active matrix, call `vgSeti` with `VG_MATRIX_MODE` as the first argument:

```
vgSeti(VG_MATRIX_MODE, VG_MATRIX_GLYPH_USER_TO_SURFACE);
/* now vgTranslate, vgRotate, etc will operate on VG_MATRIX_GLYPH_USER_TO_SURFACE */
```